# Keep a button disabled till a particular time - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and dart. I am building an app like a music/music video app and I want to keep a button disabled till a particular time and enable it when I want to launch a video. It will not be for a particular user its for all together. I have not tried to write code as I am unaware as to how to start on this. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can simply be done using a boolean variable that will control if button is enabled or not (remember providing `null` to `onPressed` will make the button behave as disabled), and as you didn't provide any code i came up with an example on my own that the button become clickable once the text change to `pause` in your cause it will be while the video is playing.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _isPlaying = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          child: Text(_isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() => _isPlaying = !_isPlaying);
          }
        ),
        FlatButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
          onPressed: _isPlaying
              ? () {
                  // some code to do when pressing the button
                }
              : null,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For example, I want to launch a video, let's say at 6 pm tomorrow but till then the button should be shown as disabled and only around 6 pm tomorrow the button should show enabled. So in that case do I have to set a timer for the button? So at 6 pm tomorrow when they click on the button they can access the video.

Comment: check the time, set the boolean to false if the time is before the 6 pm, set it to true if it's>= 6, use DateTime class